# How to order by posts by new post and new comment

Tags: mysql

I am working on post comment system. I already made it but there are some issues regarding when ordering the posts by desc and ordering it by comment desc

This is my code

```
SELECT u.username
     , u.id
     , s.id
     , s.created
     , s.message
     , s.story_id
     , c.created
     , c.message
     , c.id
     , c.story_id 
  FROM users u
     , story s
     , comment c
 WHERE u.id = s.id 
   AND c.story_id = s.story_id
 GROUP 
    BY s.story_id //for dublicate
 ORDER 
    BY s.created DESC
     , c.created DESC
```

AND also I'd tried many queries like `RIGHT JOIN` ETC or `MAX(story.created)comment.created) DESC`

BUT THE OUTPUT:

It IS ORDERED BY NEW COMMENT if I create a post it will not display or visible in my page unless I hit a comment on it. It will order it by desc. If no comment the new post with no comment will not visible.

I want to order it in new post desc and there's new comment on it, it will ordered by desc or showed to top

Comment: Since it is doubtful that two stories will ever be created at the same time, and sorting by comments is needed, why not leave out the comments from this query completely? That way you're no longer reliant on there being a comment.

Comment: I want my story ordered by desc then if my post getting older it will showed as new if theres new comment on it.      For example facebook it will showed at the top or it will ordered by desc if theres a new comment on it ... In the other hand it will ordered by new post qnd new commwnt

Comment: OK, that is not what your query currently does. I now understand. You probably need a sub-query. Let me try.

Comment: How to do it with sub queries sir :( I am new in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with something like this. I tested it on some data, and the principle seems to work.

```
SELECT
  *,
  IFNULL((SELECT MAX(comment.created) 
          FROM comment 
          WHERE comment.story_id = story.story_id), 0) AS lastCommented
FROM 
  users,
  story
WHERE 
  users.id = story.id 
ORDER BY 
  GREATEST(story.created, lastCommented) DESC
```

As you can see this is a basic query, which could also be written as a JOIN query, with two special features:

1. A **sub-query** that computes the latest time a comment for a story was created. If no comment is there, the time will be zero.
2. The ordering is done on which one is greater, the time of the story or the last comment.

This is slightly ugly, and there is another solution. You could create a new field in the story table containing the latest time a comment was made. That would remove the need for the sub-query altogether.

Comment: @Bryan Don't forget the suggestion I made at the bottom of my answer, I think that's the best approach.

Comment: This is slightly ugly, and there is another solution. You could create a new field in the story table containing the latest time a comment was made. That would remove the need for the sub-query altogether.   ///I AM NEW TO PHP MYSQLI I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO IT SIR :(

Comment: Well, then it is time to learn. Adding fields in a database and putting data in them are basic operations, and not something I should need to explain. There are [many fine tutorials](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql).

Comment: The only ugly part of this is the comma.

Comment: Thank you so much sir It will BIG helped for me